# Summarize after group_by dplyr returns single value

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I'm new with dplyr package, hopefully the question is not too silly.

Take the data.frame

`test= data.frame(aoi_id = c(15651,19975,15998,15842, 15651,19975,15998,15842),  ge_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),  ADJSTK = c(50, 54, 56, 50))`

I want to summarise it as the function aggregate would do like:

`aggregate(eu["ADJSTK"],eu["aoi_id"], mean, na.rm=T)`

I wrote the following:

`test %>% group_by(aoi_id) %>% summarise(ADJSTK = mean(ADJSTK, na.rm = T))`

Instead of returning average ADJSTK by aoi_id, I get a simple mean of ADJSTK accross the whole dataset.
Can you help me figuring out what is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Most likely you have `plyr` loaded in your environment. Try `test %>% group_by(aoi_id) %>% dplyr::summarise(ADJSTK = mean(ADJSTK, na.rm = T))`

Comment: Ah yes! That was it. Many thanks.